# Как собрать информацию в комментариях с html страницы на Python

Tags: python, html, регулярные-выражения, re, веб-скрейпинг

На вход есть html код

```
html = "<html><body><!-- Comment 1 --><p>Some text</p><!-- Comment 2 --></body></html>"

print(re.findall(r"<!-- \w+ ?\d* ?--!?>", html))
```

на выходе должно все выглядеть

```
list = ['Comment 1', 'Comment 2']
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33138937/4827341

Answer (score 0):

Можно это сделать вот так:

```py
import re
html = "<html><body><!-- Comment 1 --><p>Some text</p><!-- Comment 2 --></body></html>"
find=re.findall (r"(?<=<!--)[^(\-\-\>)]*(?=-->)", html)
x=[i.strip() for i in find]
print(x)
```

Вывод:

```
['Comment 1', 'Comment 2']
```